# C# Xamarin Visual Studios Use different kind of UIView to display information for UITextField.InputView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

So I have been able to get a UIPickerView to work with this code.  I am able to see the files in a picker when i click the textfield.

-filesInPath comes from a dropbox connection.

-AddClassDropboxPathTextBox is a textfield.

```html
public override void ViewDidLoad(){
  base.ViewDidLoad();
  setupFilePicker();
}
public void setupFilePicker(){
  PickerModelmodel = new PickerModel(filesInPath);
  UIPickerView picker = new UIPickerView();
  picker.Model = model;

  UIToolbar pickerToolbar = new UIToolbar();
  pickerToolbar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
  pickerToolbar.Translucent = true;
  pickerToolbar.SizeToFit();

  UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Choose", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, (s, e) => {
    AddClassDropboxPathTextBox.ResignFirstResponder();
  });
  pickerToolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { doneButton }, true);
  AddClassDropboxPathTextBox.InputView = picker;
  AddClassDropboxPathTextBox.InputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar;
}
public class PickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
  public List<string> Items { get; private set; }
  public Int32 SelectedIndex { get; set; }
  public PickerModelSource(List<String> items)
  {
     SelectedIndex = 0;
     tems = items;
   }
}
```

My problem Is I don't want to use a picker.  I want to use a UITableView, so I can allow the user to search through their dropbox file structure.  I have tried to replace UIPickerViewModel with a UITableViewSource.  When I click the textfield only the toolbar shows up, and I get no errors.

```html
TableViewSource source = new PTableViewSource(filesInPath);
UITableView picker = new UITableView();
picker.Source = source;
```

My hope is someone can help me figure out a way to get a UITableView to work instead of UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Pickers generally come with a predefined space they take up, while UITableViews do not.  So a solution is something like this.  It should be noted that in the size only the y value really matters.

```html
UITableView table = new UITableView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(0, 0), new CoreGraphics.CGSize(1, 100)));
```